# 301 Redirect Old URL to New Wordpress Page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I just migrated one of my old websites to wordpress but running into issues with the 301's of the old url's

old url
/11/companyname

new url
/office/companyname/

This is the code i came up with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(.*)?$ /office/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

It redirects fine when i add the trailing slash i.e. /11/companyname/ but not without.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Rule,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(.*)/?$ /office/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

It makes trailing slash optional.